# Jupyter notebook display issue (after hiding the header and maintoolbar)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Jupyter notebook for teaching purpose, and my projector has only a tiny amount of pixels to display. Thus, every inch on the screen matters.

I have added the following settings to `~\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py` in order to hide the header and maintoolbar, which should take *half* the space on the screen.

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
    $('div#header').hide();
    $('div#maintoolbar').hide();
});
```

However, I should have a vacant banner towards the end of the page when I open a Jupyter notebook. On my larger screen in my office, the banner looks as follows:
[image]

This gap towards the bottom of the page is fixed in terms of height in pixel; and should **grow** if I enlarge the fonts of the page. Both are *bad* since they take up much of the display room on a tiny projector.

How can I remove this blank banner at the end of the page?

### Screenshot explaining the situation in more detail.

As Chrome is suggested by @TMWP, I am testing out Jupyter in Chrome. Similar observation, and independent of where I am in the document. I zoom in and out, and scroll up and down, to demonstrate the problem *on my home monitors*.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the size of this area is the difference between the size of body and the size of the "site" div. I tried this and it disappeared:

```css
#site {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish that at some point in the last two and half years someone had answered your question, because here I am facing the exact same dilemma, wanting to remove the blank space at the bottom, and I see no answer here waiting for me. Very frustrating.

Comment: try Jupyter Lab if this is an option. I have zoomed in to the maximum (500%) and do not see that big fat banner at the bottom at all.